# Enviando um echo icmp em C

Tags: c, redes

Estou estudando o uso de raw sockets e seu funcionamento na linguagem C, mas fiquei com uma duvida:

> Quando eu envio o echo, preciso dar valor para o checksum do meu cabeçalho icmp que enviará o mesmo, estou precisando criar essa função para que meu algoritmo funcione corretamente "somaParaVerificação", alguém tem uma ideia?

Envio abaixo o código do cabeçalho de icmp abaixo:

**icmp.h**

```
#ifndef __ICMP_H__
#define __ICMP_H__

struct icmphdr {
    uint8_t   type;  
    uint8_t   code;   
    uint16_t  checksum;    
    uint16_t  id;        
    uint16_t  seqNum; 
    uint32_t  data[ ];  
} __attribute__((__packed__));

#endif
```

Completando o icmp

```
icmphdr = (struct icmphdr *)buffer; //zera o icmphdr a partir do buffer
icmphdr->type = ECHO_REQ; //seta o tipo de pacote
icmphdr->id = htons(getpid() & 0xffff); //seta o id do pacote
icmphdr->seqNum = htons(sequencia++); //seta o numero de sequencia requisitado
setsockopt(descritorArquivoSocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, tamanhoEndereco);
icmphdr->checksum = somaParaVerificacao(buffer, tamanhoEndereco);
```

Comment: não manjo muito ainda dessa área, mas acho que isso pode te ajudar https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/learning_by_doing_writing_your é em python mas da uma noção dos passos. Você também pode olhar o próprio source code do traceroute e ver como é implementado.

Comment: Como eu faço para olhar o source code do traceroute?

Comment: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~jrb/tcpip/misc.src/traceroute.c

Comment: da apple http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-307.0.1/traceroute.tproj/traceroute.c